# How to modify JMS queue load in spring batch 4.0.0M2

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-batch

I am writing items to an ActiveMQ queue in flow1 and reading/write them to a database in flow2. I want flow1 one to be run only 1/6 of the times of flow2, so that I keep my queue near empty. I tryed making a split inside the split with flow and step2 configuration, but this didn't work.

What do I need to make this work? Is there a special setting to achieve something like this?

```
     @Bean
     public Job multiThreadedStepJob() {

         Flow flow1 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflow1").from(step()).end();
         Flow flow2 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflow2").from(step2()).end();
         Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("splitflow").split(infrastructureConfiguration.taskExecutor())
                                                               .add(flow1, flow2).build();

return jobBuilders.get("multiThreadedStepJob")
                              .start(splitFlow)
                              .end()
                              .build();
        }
```

Comment: Why even use the queue? Why not just read from your source and write them to the database in a single step?

Comment: Because I would like to see how this is possible and I could not find an example of it anywhere.

Comment: I'm all for asking what-if's, but in this particular use case, I would advise against sticking a queue in the middle of 2 steps. It just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I know, I got it working with a rabbitMQ server now. It's slower, but now I see how this works (it's my first queue ever :)). I would never use this setup  in an environment that's in use because it's slower then without the queue.